# Change the range of cells based on another range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need to change a cell based on another cells value and the following code works perfectly for me.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$D$10")) Is Nothing Then _
Sheets("contract").Range("$D$11").ClearContents
End Sub
```

I need to extend this code to a range of cells, what i mean by this is F11 should change based on F10 and H11 should change based on H10. I know I can hard code these but, I am thinking that there might be a smarter solution. Please help

Thanks
Harsha Ganipineni

Comment: use "next range" key word to change the cell values based on previous cell. You can also use "D" + "value of cell" to set cell value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    'only react to changes in A10:Z10
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A10:Z10"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then '<<EDIT 
          Sheets("contract").Range(rng.address()).Offset(1,0).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, The solution is not working, its throwing up and error at offset.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake - missed `Not` from the marked line.  You'll need to adjust the `Intersect` line for the range where you want to respond to changes.